# How to validate Symfony form input MoneyType?

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

How do you validate form posts with the [MoneyType Field](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/money.html)?

It's bad enough that [it uses `input type="text"` instead of `type="number"`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38190891/4233593), but worse it doesn't matter what's input, like *"asdf"*, the response is always: `valid form posted.` How can I get useful error messages instructing the user that they need to put in a valid money amount, such as *"43.21"*?

I tried `'error_bubbling' => true` on the add options, `{{ form_errors(form) }}` in the twig view, and `$form->getErrors()` in the controller as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6980028/4233593), but those are always empty because no matter what, `$form->isValid()` always returns true regardless of user input.

---

## Project Structure:

```
.
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── pub
│   └── scratch.php
├── vendor
│   └── ...
└── views
    └── form.html.twig
```

## `scratch.php`

```
<?php require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
use Symfony\Component\Form\Forms;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\MoneyType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\HttpFoundation\HttpFoundationExtension;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator;
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Form\TwigRenderer;
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Form\TwigRendererEngine;
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\FormExtension;
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\TranslationExtension;

// the Twig file that holds all the default markup for rendering forms
// this file comes with TwigBridge
$defaultFormTheme = 'form_div_layout.html.twig';

$appVariableReflection = new \ReflectionClass('\Symfony\Bridge\Twig\AppVariable');
$vendorTwigBridgeDir = dirname($appVariableReflection->getFileName());
// the path to your other templates
$viewsDir = realpath(__DIR__.'/../views');

$twig = new Twig_Environment(new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(array(
    $viewsDir,
    $vendorTwigBridgeDir.'/Resources/views/Form',
)));
$formEngine = new TwigRendererEngine(array($defaultFormTheme));

$twig->addExtension(
    new FormExtension(new TwigRenderer($formEngine))
);

$twig->addExtension(
    new TranslationExtension(new Translator('en'))
);

$formEngine->setEnvironment($twig);

// create your form factory as normal
$formFactory = Forms::createFormFactoryBuilder()
    ->addExtension(new HttpFoundationExtension())
    ->getFormFactory();

$formBuilder = $formFactory->createBuilder();

$formBuilder->add("amount", MoneyType::class, [
  'currency' => 'USD',
  'error_bubbling' => true
]);

$form = $formBuilder->getForm();

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();

$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {

    die('valid form posted.');

}

$form->getErrors(true);

echo $twig->render('form.html.twig', array(
    'form' => $form->createView(),
));
```

## `form.html.twig`

```
{{ form_start(form) }}

    {{ form_errors(form) }}

    {{ form_widget(form) }}

    <input type="submit" />

{{ form_end(form) }}
```

## `composer.json`

```
{
    "require": {
        "symfony/form": "^3.1",
        "symfony/twig-bridge": "^3.1",
        "symfony/translation": "^3.1",
        "symfony/http-foundation": "^3.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of your 'scratch.php' file? Why not instead use a Controller file? I'm just asking, since you have a lot of code in the 'scratch.php' file that doesn't seem necessary... and you also put it under the folder `pub`, which is not a Symfony standard. Maybe there is a reason why you are creating your project this way - can you explain?

Comment: @AlvinBunk Standalone minimal, complete, verifiable example. I'm not using the framework, testing the waters with Symfony because the components are supposedly hailed to be modular.

Comment: Why don't you simply use the NumberType field instead of the MoneyType for your use case ?

Comment: @Alsatian because I'm dealing with currency money, not just a number, and I'd like to take advantage of other properties of that class such as a wrapper for international currency exchanges - and the input type number is actually the core problem with my [linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38190891/4233593).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I was missing the [Validator component](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Validator/Validation.html).

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;

// Set up the Validator component
$validator = Validation::createValidator();
```

Then I needed to add the [validator extension](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Validator/ValidatorExtension.html) to the form factory.

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Validator\ValidatorExtension;

// create your form factory as normal
$formFactory = Forms::createFormFactoryBuilder()
    ...
    ->addExtension(new ValidatorExtension($validator))
    ...
```

This of course needed `composer require symfony/validator`

So, I *did **not** need*

- `$form->getErrors(true)`
- `'error_bubbling' => true`
- `{{ form_errors(form) }}`

---

## `scratch.php`

```
<?php require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
use Symfony\Component\Form\Forms;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\MoneyType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\HttpFoundation\HttpFoundationExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Validator\ValidatorExtension;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Form\TwigRenderer;
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Form\TwigRendererEngine;
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\FormExtension;
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\TranslationExtension;

// the Twig file that holds all the default markup for rendering forms
// this file comes with TwigBridge
$defaultFormTheme = 'form_div_layout.html.twig';

$appVariableReflection = new \ReflectionClass('\Symfony\Bridge\Twig\AppVariable');
$vendorTwigBridgeDir = dirname($appVariableReflection->getFileName());
// the path to your other templates
$viewsDir = realpath(__DIR__.'/../views');

$twig = new Twig_Environment(new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(array(
    $viewsDir,
    $vendorTwigBridgeDir.'/Resources/views/Form',
)));
$formEngine = new TwigRendererEngine(array($defaultFormTheme));

$twig->addExtension(
    new FormExtension(new TwigRenderer($formEngine))
);

$twig->addExtension(
    new TranslationExtension(new Translator('en'))
);

$formEngine->setEnvironment($twig);

// Set up the Validator component
$validator = Validation::createValidator();

// create your form factory as normal
$formFactory = Forms::createFormFactoryBuilder()
    ->addExtension(new HttpFoundationExtension())
    ->addExtension(new ValidatorExtension($validator))
    ->getFormFactory();

$formBuilder = $formFactory->createBuilder();

$formBuilder->add("amount", MoneyType::class, [
  'currency' => 'USD'
]);

$form = $formBuilder->getForm();

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();

$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {

    die('valid form posted.');

}

$form->getErrors(true);

echo $twig->render('form.html.twig', array(
    'form' => $form->createView(),
));
```

## `form.html.twig`

```
{{ form_start(form) }}

    {{ form_widget(form) }}

    <input type="submit" />

{{ form_end(form) }}
```

## `composer.json`

```
{
    "require": {
        "symfony/form": "^3.1",
        "symfony/twig-bridge": "^3.1",
        "symfony/translation": "^3.1",
        "symfony/http-foundation": "^3.1"
        "symfony/validator": "^3.1"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach one ore more Constraints to your form field like this :

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Regex;

$formBuilder->add("amount", MoneyType::class, [
  'currency' => 'USD',
  'error_bubbling' => true,
  'constraints' => [
    new Regex(array('pattern'=>'/\d+(\.\d+)?/','message'=>'must be numeric')),
  ]
]);
```

Then if the constraint is violated the message 'must be numeric' will be displayed and your form won't be valid.

Built in constraints are defined here :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints.html

Validation usage is explained here :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#using-a-form-without-a-class

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Exception\UndefinedOptionsException' with message 'The option "constraints" does not exist.`

Comment: Do you still have this error with the validator component ?

Comment: Thanks for checking back in, but there are actually lots of problems with this answer. 1) Your `use` statement has a typo, should be plural `Constraints` not singular `Constraint`. 2) It fails to catch alphabetic characters - maybe because the default MoneyType validator trumps it. 3) It fails on a valid amount, such as "12.34", plus it throws a PHP Warning `preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash`

Comment: You've fixed 1 & 3, but it's still not throwing the `'must be numeric'` message. It stops with the default `This value is not valid.`

Comment: 'This value is not valid' is written in you {{ form_errors(form) }} block ? Strange

Comment: No, I removed that block. It's written in `{{ form_widget(form) }}`

Comment: It wpuld be easier to uqe the full framework to have all debuf informations ... Can you reuse the two blocks and replace (form) with form.amount ? And here check that this message is provided vy the form_errors(form.amount) ?

Comment: I appreciate your interest, but I'm fine with the default validator now that I've got it working. You've got the full source code here if you want to try to reproduce your custom validation message. Edit your question if you get it working and ping me.